# Ошибка "g++ could not be spawned" в Atom-е

Tags: c++, atom

При запуске C++ кода в Atome через пакет "gpp-compiler", выдаёт абракадабру - g++ could not be spawned. Is it installed and on your path? If so please open an issue on the package spawning the process - при этом я сделал всё что требовалось, установил компилятор и добавил его в PATH ... как исправить эту заразу ?

Comment: откройте обычную консоль и попробуйте запустить g++. Работает? если нет, ищите проблему в инсталляции и настройках винды. если да - тогда уже виноват атом.

Comment: @KoVadim "g++" не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.

Comment: а если g++.exe ?

Comment: таже самая фигня

Comment: прописывайте полный путь к исполняемому файлу

Comment: либо правильно добавить в PATH