# Ошибка “g++ could not be spawned” в Atom-е

Tags: gcc, atom

При запуске C++ кода в Atome через пакет "gpp-compiler", выдаёт абракадабру - g++ could not be spawned. Is it installed and on your path? If so please open an issue on the package spawning the process - при этом я сделал всё что требовалось, установил компилятор и добавил его в PATH ... как исправить эту заразу ?

P.s: из за проблем с учётной записью, выкладываю вопрос второй раз :)

По просьбе комментаторов прилагаю (хз, как правильно пишется) текст к вопросу:

> C:\Python38\Scripts;C:\Python38;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH;C:\Program
> Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI
> Technologies\ATI.ACE\CoreStatic;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\Users\raibi\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\raibi\AppData\Local\atom\bin

Comment: А смысл выкладывать второй раз? Закроют же как [дубликат](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1186850/%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-g-could-not-be-spawned-%d0%b2-atom-%d0%b5)

Comment: на тот вопрос я отвечать комментаторам не могу - у меня нету 50 балов репутации

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60848150/error-g-could-not-be-spawned-is-it-installed-and-on-your-path - может быть поможет ... но лучше Atom выкинуть. Толстый конструктор. Лучше поставить `MSYS2` с нужными компиляторами/либами +`QtCreator`.

Comment: Первое что интересно было бы узнать, откройте командную строку, и выполните следующую команду, и приложите полученный текст в вопрос: `echo %PATH%`. Как только я удалил `mingw` пакет, который был у меня установлен при помощи `Chocolatey`, у меня стало выбивать ту же самаую ошибку, так что без выполнения вами команды, увы не обойтись.

Comment: @mik.ov вывело кучу путей PATH подряд

Comment: @user409986 Все что там вывело, добавьте в вопрос

Comment: @user409986 Вот и ваша проблема, нет у вас в `PATH` пути к папке с компилятором

Comment: вот только PATH я сделал :)